# Phone State Receiver Not working in Oppo

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver

I created a basic app to check whether broadcast is received when phone state is changed, but it is not working. I tried with making outgoing call and incoming calls too. I realized these are common issues with Vivo, Honor etc. Here is Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jss.servicetester">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".ReceiverMe">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is code for receiver:

```
package jss.servicetester;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by DELL WORLD on 5/28/2017.
 */

public class ReceiverMe extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String LOGTAG = "Receiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                   Log.d(LOGTAG, "action:" + intent.getAction());

    }
}
```

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

started working in oppo F3 after making some changes in battery options for application. Like Unfreeze app in background.